# Error while makemigrations, relation for custom user

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I am currently in the middle of this project and the makemigration command is throwing an error.
Previously I used migrated but it worked fine. The error line it is showing was added before and was migrated successfully too. This is the Error

```
    E:\Projects\V-conn-API>docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations base"
[+] Running 1/0
- Container v-conn-api-db-1  Running                                                                              0.0s
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "base_user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "base_user" WHERE "base_user"."v_id" ...
                            ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 393, in execute
    self.check()
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/checks.py", line 82, in check_user_model
    if isinstance(cls().is_anonymous, MethodType):
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 477, in __init__
    val = field.get_default()
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 850, in get_default
    return self._get_default()
File "/app/base/models.py", line 50, in generate_vid
    if not User.objects.filter(v_id = vid).exists():
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 808, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 561, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1145, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "/py/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "base_user" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "base_user" WHERE "base_user"."v_id" ...
```

This is my Model.
The error in generate_vid() wasnt showing previously and it also passed the test code.
The generate_vid() function returns a 10 digit unique hexadecimal number in string format though ig.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import(
                                        BaseUserManager,
                                        AbstractBaseUser,
                                        PermissionsMixin,
                                        )


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Model for user manager"""

    def create_user(self, username, password, **params):
        """Create and return a user"""
        u_type = params.pop('usertype')
        p_username = params.pop('parent_username', 0)

        if(u_type=='v'):
            params.update({'parent_id': 0})

        else:
            parent_id = User.objects.get(username = p_username).first()['parent_id']
            params.update({'parent_id': parent_id})

        user = self.model(username=username, **params)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, **params):
        """Create and return a user"""
        params.setdefault('is_staff',True)
        params.setdefault('is_superuser',True)
        params.setdefault('is_active',True)

        if params.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if params.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(username, password, **params)

def generate_vid():
    """Generates a vid for the users"""
    not_unique = True
    while not_unique:
        vid = get_random_string(10, 'abcdefg0123456789')
        if not User.objects.filter(v_id = vid).exists():
            not_unique=False

        return vid


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """Models for user"""

    v_id = models.CharField(
                            max_length=10,
                            default=generate_vid,
                            primary_key = True,
    )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique = True)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=0)
    usertype = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('f', 'family'), ('v', 'veteran')])


    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['usertype']
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key in your `User` class to the `User` model - it could be this circular reference that is causing the problem. Django's documentation is very helpful on creating user models:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: Then how do I declare self referential foreign key in the User Model

Comment: And the problem isn't solved yet... I tried deleting the foreignkey

Comment: Do you get the same error?

Comment: Well thanks for your kind help. The problem is solved.  The thing was I needed to migrate the models step by step. There was a function in models which was calling a field. and that field was to be created on the same migration.

Comment: That's good, what was the problem in the end?

Comment: No problem actually. As I said I am new to django and the migrations were working fine. The function generate_vid() was caling User.V_id and the field wasnt even created in the model. Datz y!!! Thankx